# What are the advantages and disadvantages for the different ways of instantiating objects?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, instantiation

There are several ways of initialising an object, e.g. copy assignment, copy initialisation , direct initialisation, etc. The following snippet show some of them (not sure if it includes all the possibilities

```
class A{
    A(int) { }      // converting constructor
    A(int, int) { } // converting constructor (C++11)
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};

class B{
    explicit B(int) { }
    explicit B(int, int) { }
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};

int main(){
    A a1 = 1;      // OK: copy-initialization selects A::A(int)
    A a2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization selects A::A(int)
    A a3 {4, 5};   // OK: direct-list-initialization selects A::A(int, int)
    A a4 = {4, 5}; // OK: copy-list-initialization selects A::A(int, int)
    A a5 = (A)1;   // OK: explicit cast performs static_cast
    if (a1) ;      // OK: A::operator bool()
    bool na1 = a1; // OK: copy-initialization selects A::operator bool()
    bool na2 = static_cast<bool>(a1); // OK: static_cast performs direct-initialization

    B b1 = 1;      // error: copy-initialization does not consider B::B(int)
    B b2(2);       // OK: direct-initialization selects B::B(int)
    B b3 {4, 5};   // OK: direct-list-initialization selects B::B(int, int)
    B b4 = {4, 5}; // error: copy-list-initialization does not consider B::B(int,int)
    B b5 = (B)1;   // OK: explicit cast performs static_cast
    if (b2) ;      // OK: B::operator bool()
    bool nb1 = b2; // error: copy-initialization does not consider B::operator bool()
    bool nb2 = static_cast<bool>(b2); // OK: static_cast performs direct-initialization
}
```

Can you provide a short explanation (maybe include some low-level clarification) of what each of those do? My question arises from the explicit specifiers, that apparently it restricts copy initialisation...but why would we want this?...then I just started asking myself about the different way of instantiation..Thanks!

Comment: "Instantiation" in C++ has to do with templates. Just stick with "initialization" or possibly "creating an object" in this context.

Comment: It seems you understand what these do pretty well already. Is the actual question mainly about why a programmer would want the `explicit` keyword?

Comment: Copy assignment does not initialise an object.   It relies on the object already being initialised (by a constructor) so it is in a valid state, and (potentially) changes that state.

Comment: The advantages is that having a dozen ways to initialize an object gives everyone flexibility.  It serves to distract from the spaces-v-tabs holy war, and the "where the curly braces go?" holy war.  Now we can have a new holy war.

Comment: https://twitter.com/timur_audio/status/1004017362381795329

Comment: There is no silver bullet.

Comment: And all the `auto` variants, `auto a6 = A(6);` yada yada.

Comment: @aschepler The snippet I found it in the web. While I do know how to differentiate some of them, I dont know the proper advantages and disadvantages of each of them. I would like to use when to use what. And yes, I think that this question relates to why a programmer should want to use the explicit keyword. Thank you!